# Using a switch statement to move a character

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make the NPC in my game move by using a switch statement, however it's not working.

First, I use a function to pick a number from 0 to 3 then I use the switch statement:

```
void Start()
    {

       int randomNumber = Random.Range(0, 3);

        switch (randomNumber)
        {
            case 0:// the npc moves towards
                targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
                targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x;
                targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z - 3;
                this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity * Time.deltaTime);
                break;

            case 1://the npc moves back
                targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
                targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x;
                targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z + 3;
                this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity * Time.deltaTime);
                break;

            case 2://the npc moves right
                targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
                targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x - 3;
                targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z;
                this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity * Time.deltaTime);
                break;

            case 3://the npc moves left
                targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
                targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x + 3;
                targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z;
                this.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, velocity * Time.deltaTime);
                break;

            default: break;
        }
    }
```

The number is generated, but the NPC doesn't move. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: be careful Random.Range: random integer number between min [inclusive] and max [exclusive]  so Random.Range(0, 4) will be better here

Comment: @Frenchy, yes, you are right. I'll change it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a start position with first move, use a startCoroutine..

```
void Start()
{
   StartCoroutine(FirstMove(Random.range(0,4));
}

public IEnumerator MoveToPosition(Transform transform, Vector3 position, float timeToMove)
{
    var currentPos = transform.position;
    var t = 0f;
    while (t < 1f)
    {
        t += Time.deltaTime / timeToMove;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPos, position, t);
        yield return null;
    }
    transform.position = position;
}


private void Firstmove(int randomNumber)
{

    //Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3();
    //float velocity = 10.0f;
    switch (randomNumber)
    {
        case 0: // the npc moves towards
            targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
            targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x;
            targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z - 3;
            break;

        case 1: //the npc moves back
            targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
            targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x;
            targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z + 3;
            break;

        case 2: //the npc moves right
            targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
            targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x - 3;
            targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z;
            break;

        case 3: //the npc moves left
            targetPosition.y = 1.4f;
            targetPosition.x = this.transform.position.x + 3;
            targetPosition.z = this.transform.position.z;
            break;

        default: break;
    }

    StartCoroutine(MoveToPosition(transform, targetPosition, 2f));
}
```

Comment: I did as you said, but it doesn't move. I've removed Time.Deltatime and I created the coroutine like you did. I suspect the issue has to do with this line ```yield return null;```

Comment: no yield is necessary..what is the value of velocity?  increase it...

Comment: velocity = 100f for example..careful in your example

Comment: Velocity is 15f. I put it in ```Update()``` and he moves, however he does uncontrollably, because he updates his position every frame. I want him to achieve the target position and stop.

Comment: i have modified the sample to have a smooth move.. i have added a general move. you add the amount of time you want to move

Comment: be carefull with the value of y...if its upper value, your gameobject risk to fly...if you have problem dont modify this value